# Simple Android SearchView not functioning properly

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to follow the [search interface manual](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) from android.com. I have few problems and I am not sure what I did wrong exactly.
[image]

If you want to look, here is the [project as zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UXc5_qXofcEZFWxyt_8WP3evF2ziPXpH) file.

1- The `android:hint` is not visible when I touch search icon. It comes empty. Why? If I set it programmatically it works eg.                 `searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));` Why it doesn't work from XML?
[image]

2- Search field does not get focus and keyboard does not appear automatically when I touch search icon. I need to touch to the search textfield to get focus. I believe it should get focus automatically?

3- When I write something and touch the search icon on the keyboard. I do not see any log entries logged at logcat window. What is missing?

4- (SOLVED) I tried `android:iconifiedByDefault="false"` in XML and also `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);` and it is always iconified when I start the application. Why is that happening?

- I found out that iI need to remove `collapseActionView` from `app:showAsAction` otherwise `setIconifiedByDefault(false)` does not work. Also if you remove `collapseActionView` and set `setIconifiedByDefault(false)` then it never collapses.

I am guessing I missed something somewhere but I am not sure exactly what...

So below are the steps I followed:

I started a new project with 'Basic Activity' in Android Studio 3.
It has a ready toolbar and 'Hello World' in the middle.

Then to `xml` folder I added the `searchable.xml` file with contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="Search hint text"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer">
</searchable>
```

Then changed `AndroidManifest.xml` file and added an activity:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchableActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

Then created a simple `SearchableActivity.class`. Just to log some lines.

```
package com.test.myapplication;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static String TAG = SearchableActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleIntent");
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            //use the query to search your data somehow
        }
    }
}
```

Then added to existing `menu_main.xml` the necessary item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.test.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Update: If I change to `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` and also in `MainActivity.class` if I import `import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;` then when I click on the search icon, it shows default `Search...` text gets focus automatically. But does NOT show hint from XML and still there are no log entries when I submit any information.
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I realized that if I put the `intent-filter` and the `meta` part under `MainActivity` I am getting the search intent inside main activity. But I don't understand why it does not start the `SearchableActivity`. Because manual page for [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#ReceivingTheQuery) clearly says:

> When a user executes a search from the search dialog or widget, the system starts your searchable activity and sends it a ACTION_SEARCH intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all I needed to do was to forward the intent to correct activity from `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
// Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, SearchableActivity.class);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
if (searchManager != null)
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

Instead of this

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

Comment: I tried that and it is just solves 1 issue. Now the search field gets focus.

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen try this **`app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"`**

Comment: It makes no difference. My understanding is that `always` means action won't go to menu. But I found out that I should remove `collapseActionView` and it won't collapse. Anyway, the biggest problem is that the `SearchView` does not seem to be doing anything when I submit text and I don't understand why?

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen for test case use `AppCompatActivity `   instead of `ListActivity `

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen I have downloaded the project trying to open

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160851/discussion-between-evren-yurtesen-and-nilu).